# Module JS - Mismatched anonymous define module

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, requirejs

I've tried adding my module JS file to Magento2 but for whatever reason it seems to return this error:

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function($)

My `view/frontend` file structure:

```
|-frontend
|-----layout
|---------default_head_blocks.xml
|-----requirejs-config.js
|-----templates
|---------helloworld.phtml
|-----web
|---------js
|-------------main.js
```

> requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/main'
    ]
};
```

> web/js/main.js

```
define(
    ['jquery'],
    function($)
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log('hello world');
    }
);
```

> layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/main.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

What am I doing wrong in including my JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you doing wrong by including your JS is that your js file `main.js`, you should declare it in `requirejs-config.js` and not in `default_head_blocks.xml`

Here is a full exemple:

> 1. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module: 'Vendor_module/js/main',
        }
    }
};
```

> 2. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/main.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('hello myscript');
           //put all your mainjs code here
       }
});
```

> 3. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Don't forget to :**

- `clean the cache`
- `clean var/view_preprocessed content`
- `clean pub/static content`
- `deploy the static content : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, add the js, you may use a template phtml (using layout file)

To load the javascript on every page, place the template on a layout file that is loaded on all pages.

the phtml template may be like the below

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
      "*": {
          "module_name/js/main":{
              "base_url":"<?=$block->getBaseUrl(); ?>"
          }
      }
    }
</script>
```

the above snippet will load you javascript file once your file is in web/js module folder

then I would change your js from

```
define(
    ['jquery'],
    function($)
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log('hello world');
    }
);
```

to

```
define(
    ['jquery'],
    function($)
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log('hello world');

        return function(config, element) {
          console.log('hello world inside for instance');
          // here you can see the base_url from your js snippet and the dom element is #example
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: do I have to use a .phtml file? I'd much prefer to keep everything separate?

Comment: I can see your point. My answer is what I use and what I have been trained to use as well.

Comment: Just feels .. a bad practice? Not sure .. I know outside of M2 mixing JS + PHP is seen as something you should avoid, but M1 + M2 seem to use this practice a lot ... I'll change my code as suggested but if a method comes along that allows separation of JS + PHP I will probs opt for that :)

Comment: didn't seem to work :s

Comment: I have this public repository (see https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/punchhole/src/master/) showing an example of js file.. it uses ui component but the script that I give above should work just as well insipring you from this repo

Comment: of course, module_name needs to be replaced by a module that you have created in app/code, right?