# How to add custom css and js file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-field

I want to add my custom css and js files in my catalog page. Please let me know how to add in header.

I added catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <css src="Sub_Categorylist::css/category_css_slider.css"/>
        <css src="Sub_Categorylist::css/category_css_theme_slider.css"/>

        <script src="Sub_Categorylist::js/category_slider.js"/>
        <script src="Sub_Categorylist::js/category_slider.min.js"/>
    </head>

</page>
```

Please let me know is there any corrections.

Thanks In Advance..!

Answer (score 3):

## **JS:**

The best way to add a `JS` in Magento (theme or module) is with **REQUIREJS**.

#### To add a js in **theme** via `Requirejs`:

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('hello myscript');
           //put all your myfile js code here
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

## **CSS:**

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/yourstyle.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**note :**

All these will be displayed in theme, if you just need catalog page, you replace `Magento_Theme` with `Magento_Catalog`

Comment: Hi, i like to add in my module files. i call css and js files like above my updated question.

Comment: Look this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255077/48355

Comment: i like to add 2 js files, one is (custom.mim.js) how to call that .min.js files?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your layout file `catalog_product_view.xml`(Product Page), `catalog_category_view.xml`(Category Page)

```
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/custom.css"/>
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/custom.js"/>
</head>
```

Comment: i added in my module .xml file like you given, but i think so js file has corrupted

Comment: Where is your css or js files placed? Also please share the code you have added

Comment: i had adde my code in "app/code/Sub/Categorylist/view/frontend/web/(css)&(js)folder.

Comment: i place  " <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
            
      $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    
    });
</script>"  in my app/code/Sub/Categorylist/view/frontend/templates/category/sub.phtml but its not working

Comment: So what error are you getting when loading the css and js in layout file? So you are placing the script in template, whether the script gets loaded in frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding it on the head of a **`layout`**
Refer from this:  [Include static resources](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css)

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

        <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>

        <!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override catalog_category_view.xml file into your theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <head>  
        <script src="js/custom.js"/>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    </head>
    </body>
</page>
```